# Configure port1 of 8051 micro-controller as input

Tags: c, 8051, keil

I am writing a very simple application which allows one to change the temperature. The temperature is displayed using LEDS (BCD format)

I wrote the following code in Keil C51:

```
#include< REG51.h>

sbit select = P1^7;
sbit up = P1^0;
sbit down = P1^1;
int data room = 24;

void main()
{   int prog;
    P2 &=0x00;
    P1 |=0x83;
    prog = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if(select == 1)
            prog++;
        if(prog == 1)
        {
            if(up == 1)
                room++;
            if(down == 1)
                room--;

            P2 = room;
        }
    }
}
```

I then complied this and obtained the Intel hex file which i then tried to simulate using the [Edsim](http://www.edsim51.com/).

According to the C code the temp should change when prog=1 and when either up(p1.0) or down(p1.1) is pressed, but in the simulation it only changes when both select(p1.7) and up/down is pressed!

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prog++` means that the value of `prog` increments by 1 *every time* that the condition `select == 1` is true. This means that the condition `prog == 1` is true only on the first iteration that it's incremented.

Try changing `prog++` to `prog = 1`.

Edit: As per discussion in comments, if you wish to track the number of times `select` has gone up, you need to wait for it to be 0 again before you let `prog` be incremented again. For example:

```
int prev = select;
…
if (select != prev) {
    // select has changed from its previous state

    prev = select;
    if (prev) {
        // select went from 0 to 1
        ++prog;

        if (prog == 1) {
           // code to be executed once only on the first press
        } else if (prog == 2) {
           // code to be executed once only on the second press
        } else if (prog >= 3) {
           // code to be executed once on every subsequent press
        }
    } else {
        // select went from 1 to 0
    }
}

if (prev) {
   // select is being pressed

   if (prog == 1) {
       // code to be executed _continuously_ while select is held down
       // (after first press only)
   }
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I did `prog++` because I would be adding in more conditions to expand the functionality of my program (i.e. add `if==2` etc.). And also how does that help? In my current program, whenever `select==1` for the 2nd time, `prog` will be equal to 2 and hence it should not enter the if construct

Comment: If `prog` equals 2, then `if (prog == 1)` is obviously false because `2 != 1`. In any case you must remember that `if (select == 1)` doesn't just count the number of times the select has gone from 0 to 1, but the number of iterations where it has been 1 (without necessarily ever having been 0 at any point in between). If you wish to add more conditions, you could change it to `if (prog >= 1)` but you'll run into the same problem again and again.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. But then now how do I go about doing it? switch case would give the same problem. What i want is that when I press `select` for the fist time it should do the temperature code, when for the second time it should execute a prime number function (not implemented yet), when for the 3rd time do something else. It's like jumping from one function to another depending on the number of times `select` is pressed.

Comment: Wait for `select` to be 0 again before incrementing `prog`, e.g. something like `if (select) { if (!wasOn) { ++prog; wasOn = 1; } } else { wasOn = 0; }`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code does not reflect what you want it to do.

```
if(select == 1)
            prog++;
        if(prog == 1)
        {
```

prog is initially 0, so prog==1 will be true only for the first time you press select.

at that time it goes into the IF and check

```
if(up == 1)
                room++;
            if(down == 1)
                room--;

            P2 = room;
```

change the room current temp to +1 or -1 if up or down is pressed. since u r simulating with buttons, this means that either of the button should be pressed when you press the select.

and then it outputs the data to P2

what you need to do is:

```
while (1)
{
    if(select== 1)
    {   
        P2 = room;
    }


   if(up == 1)
       room++;
   if(down == 1)
       room--; 
}
```

you still will need to press select to update the temperature, and up/down to change temperature. If you can make yourself more clear as to how it is to work, maybe i can help more.

Comment: I am planning to expand my code to add additional functionality (i.e. something else when `select==2`, etc.). So what i want is that when i press `select`, it should go the temperature part and then only change temp when up/down is pressed. But at the same time there shouldnt be a need to press `select` to use up/down. Hopefully i am clear enough!

Comment: I know it would be better to use switch case if i want various things to be done with different `select` values but initially i am learning and testing so will switch to that later

Answer (score 0):

You should Try changing `prog++` to `prog = 1`. Let me know if that helps!